# How to add an output to the result in a while loop Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to sum all bytes in "RX packets" lines of an `ifconfig | grep "RX packets"` output.

How do I do that?

Here's my code

```
#!/usr/lib/env bash

clear

result=0

while read i; do

    line=${i##*'bytes'} | awk '{print $1;}' 
    
    (( "$result"+="$line" ))

    echo "$result"

done <<< "$(ifconfig | grep "RX packets")"
```

Also: How should I extract those lines of bytes in a better way, doing `"$(ifconfig | grep "RX packets")"` and then `line=${i##*'bytes'} | awk '{print $1;}'` seems so **ugly** and complicated

`if config | grep "RX packets"` my output:

```
        RX packets 7817232  bytes 9337993347 (9.3 GB)
        RX packets 1240058  bytes 83114376 (83.1 MB)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX packets 188707  bytes 27682805 (27.6 MB)
```

Desired result - sum of all **bytes**:

```
9337993347 + 83114376 + 27682805
```

Comment: In the line `line=${i##*'bytes'} | awk '{print $1;}'`, what input do you expect `awk` to be seeing?

Comment: It would be handy if you provided sample input and desired output, since the output of `ifconfig` varies by platform.

Comment: The number after the word bytes in ```ifconfig | grep "RX packets"```

Comment: You are missing a command substitution in the assignment to `line`.

Comment: This whole thing should be a single `awk` script, not a shell script that uses `awk` to do minimal processing on each line.

Comment: @IgorTheOverlord Again, the output of `ifconfig` varies by platform.  The closest version I can quickly find that even contains the string "RX packets" does not contain the word "bytes" on any of those lines.

Comment: @IgorTheOverlord, assignments have no output. `var=anything | bar` doesn't write anything at all to the input of `bar`. (It also doesn't create a variable named `var` that sticks around long enough to be seen by programs run later). If you want `var="$(echo anything | bar)"`, that's a different command.

Comment: Also, you want `(( result += line ))`. Definitely not `(( "$result" += "$line" ))`; you want `result` to be treated as a variable name, not as the number it expands to.

Comment: That said, if you're going to use awk, you should use awk for _everything_, including the math. (Also, if your target OS is Linux, you shouldn't use `ifconfig`  at all -- it's been unmaintained for more than a decade there, is completely unaware of a lot of modern kernel features, and consequently there are many kinds of network devices and configurations it simply can't show at all and ignores; the modern tool is iproute2, run under the name `ip`).

Comment: `ifconfig | grep "RX packets" | awk '{sum+=$5}END{print sum}'` should do the trick without all this looping and whatnot.

Comment: @JNevill, why grep instead of `awk '/RX packets/ {sum+=$5}'`?

Comment: Replace `(( "$result" += "$line" ))` by `(( result += line ))` or by `let result+=line`. `let` introduces math mode too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When assigning to a variable, even inside an arithmetic expression, use the variable name without the dollar sign.

When reading from a command list, use process substitution rather than a here string.

Also, you don't need `awk`, you can remove the substring similarly to how you removed the other part.

```bash
#! /bin/bash
result=0

while read line; do

    line=${line##*bytes}  # Remove everything up to bytes.
    line=${line%(*}       # Remove everything starting from (.
    
    (( result+=line ))
done < <(ifconfig | grep "RX packets")
echo $result
```

Comment: This is correct, but is bad advice.  This problem is best solved with `awk`.

Comment: I'd probably use Perl instead. How is "best" defined?

Comment: lol.  A very good argument could be made that "best" == "perl"!  Doing it directly in the shell like this might be good exercise, though.

Answer (score 3):

Using the shell to do arithmetic with a while/read loop is slow and clunky.  You could simply do:

```
ifconfig | awk '/RX packets/{ s += $5 } END {print s}'
```

(This assumes a particular format for the output of `ifconfig`, so this will likely fail if you use it on a different platform.)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, with `sed` and `bash`:

```
bytes=$(ifconfig | sed -n 's/.*RX packets.*bytes \([0-9]*\).*/\1/p')
echo $(( ${bytes//$'\n'/+} ))
```